# How can I update some jQuery from a text input elsewhere on the page?

Tags: jquery

I am working on little project to learn jQuery, and I have a twitter plugin which you enter a username to see the tweets of that user. Elsewhere on the site I have a simple text input field which I'm hoping can take an entry and append it to where the username is in the existing code... Is this possible? Maybe using the append string, or .text?

Where you can see rjames83, that's what I'd like to replace with the contents of a text field.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
// Get latest 6 tweets by jQueryHowto
$.jTwitter('rjames83', 6, function(data){
    $('#posts').empty();
    $.each(data, function(i, post){
        $('#posts').append(
            '<div class="post">'
            +' <div class="txt">'
            // See output-demo.js file for details
            +    post.text
            +' </div>'
            +'</div>'
        );
    });
});
```

});

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All you do is wrap the $jTwitter block in a function and pass it a parameter.

```
$(document.ready(function(){

    function getTweets(username){
        $.jTwitter(username, 6, function(data){
           //rest of your function code here...
        });
    }
    getTweets('rjames83');

});



// be sure to call "getTweets();" in the doc.ready to call the jQuery when you load the page, as it did before. Why? Wrapping the code in a function is like telling it not to do anything until you call it, instead of automatically loading as it did before.
```

Wherever you are typing in the new user to grab tweets for, simply add this to the onclick of the button to make it fire:

```
onclick="javascript: getTweets($('#textboxid').val());"
```

Comment: Thanks, all ok except in Chrome I can see the error 'getTweets is not defined' so the onclick isn't working. How can I define this?

Comment: You can write this function outside the $(document).ready(); or try adding the value of the username via regular javascript, so like document.getElementById('textboxid').value inside the getTweets call.